# Magento 2: How to add a product to the admin items ordered grid?

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, totals, admin-order-create

I am currently developing a module which pre prefills the order items grid automatically when a backend user creates an order from our CRM.

This is done via the observer event:

```
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before
```

Here's the (reduced) code:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreateModel */
    $orderCreateModel = $observer->getData('order_create_model');

    $crmProduct = $this->someFunctionWhichGivesMeTheProductFromTheCrm(1);

    $params = [
        'qty' => $crmProduct->qty,
        'custom_price' => $crmProduct->price
    ];

    $orderCreateModel->addProduct(25, $params);

    /** just tried several methods in desperation - none of them worked... **/      

    $orderCreateModel->recollectCart();
    $orderCreateModel->getQuote()->collectTotals();
    $orderCreateModel->recollectCart();
    $orderCreateModel->saveQuote();
}
```

This is the result:

[image: order items grid]

The products are added but all the totals are not calculated correctly. If I hit the button "Updated Items and Quantities" manually the prices are calculated - but with the result you see below:

[image]

Can someone please give me an advice on how to add the products correctly and or collect the totals?

Answer (score 1):

Try following way:

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AdminhtmlSalesOrderCreateProcessDataBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * AdminhtmlSalesOrderCreateProcessDataBefore constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {

        $params = [
            'qty' => 8,
            'custom_price' => 55
        ];
        $productId = 1;
        $product = $this->objectManager->create(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class
        )->setStore(
            $this->getSession()->getStore()
        )->setStoreId(
            $this->getSession()->getStoreId()
        )->load(
            $productId
        );
        $config = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($params);
        $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $config);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve session object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote
     */
    protected function getSession()
    {
        return $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve quote object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected function getQuote()
    {
        return $this->getSession()->getQuote();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But still one problem exists: The subtotal, row total and the overall calculated values are still 0. After i hit the button Update Items and Quantities it's calculated correctly. I tried to fix this by calling `getQuote()->collectTotals()` but this broke everything.

Comment: Hey working fine M2.2.4. Which version you tried?

Comment: Was running on M2.2.2 and just upgraded to 2.2.4 - still the same result.