# Plugin for after add product in admin order creation for Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order

When adding products to a new order in the admin is there a function I can hook into for a Plugin for when the product is added to the order?

[image: Creating orders in the admin]

For certain products, I need to do additional logic to the price

Comment: hope you can try this observer adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before  reference from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229002/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-to-the-admin-items-ordered-grid